# Don't know how to solve this error [Racket]: "car: contract violation expected: pair? given: '()"

Tags: racket

I'm trying to get a list with the average of the following n elements. I'm reading a csv file that has 7 columns im just using the 6th one that has number values in order to get the average.
This is the code

```
;Function that returns a list containing the values of the desired column
(define (get-column col)
  (let loop
    ([file (cdr(all-rows csv-path read-csv))]
     [result empty])
    (if (empty? file)
        result
        (loop (cdr file)
              (cond
                [(equal? col 1) (append result (list (caar file)))]
                [(equal? col 2) (append result (list (string->number(cadar file))))]
                [(equal? col 3) (append result (list (string->number(caddar file))))]
                [(equal? col 4) (append result (list (string->number(car (cdddar file)))))]
                [(equal? col 5) (append result (list (string->number(cadr (cdddar file)))))]
                [(equal? col 6) (append result (list (string->number(caddr (cdddar file)))))]
                [(equal? col 7) (append result (list (string->number(car (cdddr (cdddar file))))))]
                )))))
(define (suma-SMA col n)
  (let loop
    ([n n]
     [res 0]
     [col col])
    (if (zero? n)
        res
        (loop (sub1 n) (+ res (car col)) (cdr col)))))

(define (get-SMA days)
  (let loop
    ([col (get-column 6)]
     [result empty])
    (if (empty? col)
        result
        (loop (cdr col)(append result (list (suma-SMA col days)))))))
```

Comment: You are getting the error because `n` is longer than the length of `col`. It's not clear why you need to use `n` in `suma-SMA` at all, why not stop the sum when you get to the end of the list?

Comment: I'm trying to add a list such as '(1,2,3,4) and the solution should be '((1+2)/2, (2+3)/2, (3+4)/4)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, your `suma-SMA` function doesn't do anything like that. Apart from anything else `suma-SMA` returns an integer not another list.

Comment: The problem is in the `get-SMA` there is where i want to iterate until my `col` gets empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does what you asked for in the comments, e.g. given `(1 2 3 4)` it produces `((1+2)/2 (2+3)/2 (3+4)/2)`.

```
(define (sum list)
  (cond
    ((null? list)
     '()) ;; error?
    ((null? (cdr list))
     '())
    (else
     (cons (/ (+ (car list) (cadr list)) 2) (sum (cdr list))))))
```

I'm still a bit confused because even the combination of `get-SMA` and `suma-SMA` does nothing like this. It's completely unclear what the `days` variable is doing, as you can see I didn't need it in my code above.

So I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do, but the function above does what you actually asked for so hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: This function is not exactly what I need, but very useful, in this functioon you're getting the average of the current value and the next one `((/ (+ (car list) (cadr list)) 2)) `
But what I was serching about is about getting the average of the current value and the next n values. For example if days was 5 it should be `(/ (+(car list) (cadr list) (cdar list) (cddar list) (cdddar list))5)`. But i don't want this sum to be static. Sorry if I'm not explianing well my problem.

Comment: I have changed my suma-SMA ```(define (suma-SMA col n)
  (let loop
    ([cont n]
     [res 0]
     [col col])
    (if (zero? cont)
        (/ res n)
        (loop (sub1 cont) (+ res (car col)) (cdr col)))))``` 
And I try to add it to your code something like this
```(define (sum list n)
  (cond
    ((null? list)
     '()) ;; error?
    ((null? (cdr list))
     '())
    (else
     (cons  (suma-SMA (get-column 6) n) (sum (cdr list) n)))))```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that I found useful for my problem.

```
(define (sum list n)
  (cond
    ((null? list)
     '()) ;; error?
    ((null? (cdr list))
     '())
    (else
     (cons  (suma-SMA list n) (sum (cdr list) n)))))
```